# Form page after Form page

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am having a problem in my symfony 2 project regarding the use of form (forms without classes). The idea is to develop a sequence of forms (each one in an independent page). Similar to multistep form or wizard but exactly not the same. In each form, partial sent results are saved and a new form is called.

Currently I have a controller with a form like this:

```
public function form1Action(Request $request, $parameter){

 //Get relevant data using the $parameter...

 $defaultData = array('message' => 'Type your message here');
 $formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData);
 $formBuilder->add('sendreport', 'choice', array(
                          'choices'   => array('yes' => 'Yes', 'no' => 'No'),
                          'expanded' => true,
                          'label' => 'You will receive a full report from administrator',
                          'multiple' => false,      
                       ));

    $formBuilder->add('start', 'submit', array('label' => 'form.labels.start'));

    $form = $formBuilder->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

       if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){

          $data = $form->getData();

          return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('task_form2', array('data' => $data)));

    }     

    return $this->render('MyBundle:Default:showform1.html.twig', array('ourform' => $form->createView()));
```

}

Then, the redirected page contains a new form with similar structure to the previous one:

```
public function form2Action(Request $request, $data){

    $datasource = $data;
    $defaultData = array('message' => 'Type your message here');
    $formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('email', 'text')
        ->add('message', 'textarea')
        ->add('send', 'submit');

    $form = $formBuilder->getForm(); 


    $form->handleRequest($request);

  //WHY IS NOT SUBMMITED???

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

        if ($form->isSubmitted() /*&& $form2->isValid()*/) {

           $data2 = $form->getData();

           $data = //$data = $data2 array + $datasource array...

          return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('task_form3'), array('data' => $data));
    }
}

return $this->render('MyBundle:Default:showform2.html.twig', array('ourform' => $form->createView()));
```

}

But here is the problem, the second form called in 'task_form2' path is not submitted!¿?. When you press the send button nothing happens!.

Any idea?
What is the best way to do this? (I think it is simpler and I would not like to use multistep bundle or something like that).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why you commented out "$form->isValid()" in your form2Action?

Comment: I can uncomment it, but it is not the problem...

Comment: I have detected that in the second form of the controller form2Action,  the code inside if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') is not considered. Maybe there is something wrong with the POS request...

Comment: usually,if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')and if ($form->isSubmitted() make no sense. $form->isValid() enough. if u really need determine the request method,you can add in your route.

Comment: thank you, but does not work! I think the problem is in a different sentence of the code, but I have no idea :(

Comment: What do you have in showform2.html.twig? That may be the source of the issue. Also, I don't think passing the data submitted so far from form to form via the url is a good approach. You could put it in the session, or better still store partially complete data in the db.

Comment: Finally it was a stupid error!.. The problem was in the twig template, I was using

{{ form_widget(ourform2) }}

instead of:

{{ form_start(ourform2) }}

{{ form_widget(ourform2) }}

{{ form_end(ourform2) }}